# backup-manager [Net::FTP] Timeout error when execute it

Tags: ftp, backup

I install backup manager and after config, I try to execute it with `sudo backup-manager` but there is an error :

```
Net::FTP>>> Net::FTP(3.08_01)
Net::FTP>>>   Exporter(5.72)
Net::FTP>>>   Net::Cmd(3.08_01)
Net::FTP>>>   IO::Socket::IP(0.37)
Net::FTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.38)
Net::FTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.36)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)<<< 220 server ready - login please
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)>>> USER XXXXXX
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)<<< 331 password required
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)>>> PASS ....
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)<<< 230 login accepted
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)>>> TYPE I
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)<<< 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)>>> CWD /
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)<<< 250 OK. Current directory is /
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)>>> PASV
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,8)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)>>> STOR 2mb_file.dat
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x558b37af3978)<<< 421 Timeout
Unable to transfer /var/archives/2mb_file.dat: Timeout
Unable to transfer test file
The upload transfer "ftp" failed.
```

I try to increse `export BM_UPLOAD_FTP_TIMEOUT="30"` to `export BM_UPLOAD_FTP_TIMEOUT="3000"` but same error after a time longer...

**what's wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved by update firewall and adding iptables for ftp passive mode !